how to deal with maven install error looking for an outdated jar's parent pom that I could not find online
This is the error I am getting. This was working. I cleaned my local .m2 repository for another reason and rebuilt it from the remote jfrog artifactory. Then I started having this issue.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project glowWeb: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.autosys.liquor:glowWeb:war:4.13.8-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver:jasperserver-common-ws:jar:3.5.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.jaspersoft.jasperserver:jasperserver-common-ws:jar:3.5.0: Could not find artifact com.jaspersoft.jasperserver:server:pom:3.5.0 in ext-release-local (http://cdt-jfrogrepo.autosys.com:9080/artifactory/ext-release-local)

I could not find neither jasperserver-common-ws.jar v3.5.0, nor its parent pom online. This is because, it is very outdated. I have this jasperserver-common-ws.jar elsewhere, and I deployed this to our jfrog artifactory. However, there is no parent pom xml in this jar. I wonder how it was working good before, and now it is complaining.
As I said, first of all, I could not find this version (that is 3.5.0) of the jar online. Any suggestion on how I can get out of this issue.
I attached the contents of the pom.xml file of jasperserver-common-ws.jar below. We can see that there is a mention of a parent. I also attached a screenshot of my jfrog repo where this is deployed. This is after I deployed this jar manually into this jfrog repo.


<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.jaspersoft.jasperserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>jasperserver-common-ws</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>3.5.0</version>
  <name>Jasper Server Common WebServices</name>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.jaspersoft.jasperserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
  </parent>
  <description>Jasper Server Common WebServices Deployment</description>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.dtd</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins/>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
      <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>axis</groupId>
      <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>




